# Add Multiple ListBoxes to a PivotItem in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am fairly new to windows phone programming & I am having some trouble while adding multiple ListBoxes to a single Pivot Item, first of all, here is the code where I need help:

```
 ListBox ListA = new ListBox();
 ListBox ListB = new ListBox();


 Grid G = new Grid(); 
 PivotItem P = new PivotItem(); 

 G.Children.Add(ListA);
 G.Children.Add(ListB);

 P.Content = G;
```

Both Lists contain "Images", which are successfully displayed on the screen (Vertically aligned Icons basically)

My problem:

The last List added is scrollable & the previous one freezes, I *cannot* do anything in XAML because my Grid/Pivot are created programmatically, also the images in the second List are "clickable" but they are not in the first, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to Me that the 2nd ListBox overlap the 1st. Try to declare two columns for the `Grid G` , and put each ListBox in corresponding column, for example :

```
ListBox ListA = new ListBox();
ListBox ListB = new ListBox();

Grid G = new Grid(); 
PivotItem P = new PivotItem(); 

//declare two columns with equal width (Width="*" for each)
G.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
G.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

G.Children.Add(ListA);
G.Children.Add(ListB);

//set ListA in column 0 and ListB in column 1
Grid.SetColumn(ListA, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(ListB, 1);

 P.Content = G;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried doing this, now the first List gets displayed but the second one doesn't, no images are displayed on the second column, thanks!

Comment: That's a good sign. I suspect you have a kind of margin/padding that push the 2nd listbox to right (out of the visible area), try to remove the padding/margin.

Comment: Ok yeah, it was the padding, but unfortunately the problem persists, "ListB" images are scrollable/clickable while the images from "ListA" after dsiplayed and are frozen, can't click or scroll them :S

Comment: I got an error in my sample code, `Grid.SetRow(...)` should've been `Grid.SetColumn(...)`. If this still doesn't work, I'd suggest to post more of the actual-relevant code. All answers (including this one) is just a guess without seeing the actual codes

Comment: You sir, are AWESOME! that did the trick, it was pretty obvious it should've been "SetColumns", even I wasn't paying attention, haha, Thank you SO much! :D

Comment: My work can finally proceed, been stuck here for a day, how do I mark this as an answer? :)